# The parameter 'address' cannot be an empty string. Parameter name: address

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, forms, email

I realize this question has come up before but the answers don't answer my question directly, I've also searched the net for the last few days.

The problem is, I have a asp.net VB form that sends to email.. However, it comes up with the error **"The parameter 'address' cannot be an empty string. Parameter name: address"** when I click on Submit. But the strange thing is, it still actually sends the email through with all relevant info included.

Anyone have any ideas as to why it's giving an error but still sending?
I feel like it's something simple, but it's doing my head in! Let me know if you need other code snippets.

Code Behind:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.Mail

Partial Class _default
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub submitButton_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles submitButton.Click

        'send new confirmation email
    Try

        'create the email message
        Dim EmailMsg As New MailMessage()

        'set the address and subject
        EmailMsg.From = New MailAddress(emailTextBox.Text.ToString)
        EmailMsg.To.Add("myemailaddress")
        EmailMsg.Subject = "Website enquiry from " + firstnameTextBox.Text.ToString

        'set the content
        EmailMsg.Body = "First Name: " + firstnameTextBox.Text.ToString + "<br>" +
                        "Last Name: " + lastnameTextBox.Text.ToString + "<br>" +
                        "Reply to: " + emailTextBox.Text.ToString + "<br>" +
                        "Ph No.: " + phoneTextBox.Text.ToString + "<br>" +
                        "Dropdown value:" + DropDownList1.SelectedValue + "<br>" +
                        "Website Address: " + webAddressTextBox.Text.ToString + "<br>" +
                        "Other option: " + otherTextBox.Text.ToString

        EmailMsg.IsBodyHtml = True

        'send the message
        Dim smtp As New SmtpClient()
        smtp.Send(EmailMsg) 'uses web.config settings

        'if successful clear form and show success message
        firstnameTextBox.Text = String.Empty
        lastnameTextBox.Text = String.Empty
        emailTextBox.Text = String.Empty
        phoneTextBox.Text = String.Empty
        DropDownList1.SelectedValue = Val("0")
        webAddressTextBox.Text = String.Empty
        otherTextBox.Text = String.Empty

        lblMessage.Text = "Message sent successfully!"

    Catch ex As Exception
        'show error message if unsuccessful
        lblMessage.Text = ex.Message

    End Try

End Sub
End Class
```

Web.config:

```
<configuration>
<system.net>
<mailSettings>
  <smtp>
    <network host="server" 
             port="25"
             userName="myemailaddress"
             password="mypassword"/>
  </smtp>
</mailSettings>
```

Thanks heaps in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The parameter 'addresses' cannot be an empty string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20127918/the-parameter-addresses-cannot-be-an-empty-string)

Answer (score 2):

Try using

```
EmailMsg.To.Add(New MailAddress("myemailaddress"))
```

I think you need to add MailAddress objects to your To list. I do in my code and I don't get any errors.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I have changed my code to reflect your suggestion however it still gives the error message and sends the message

Comment: Have you debugged your code to check the value of `emailTextBox.Text.ToString`? If that is not valid, then it would be the From address that is causing the problem (and would perhaps explain why the email still gets to the destination as the To address is not the problem).