# The parameter 'addresses' cannot be an empty string

Tags: c#, asp.net, system.net.mail

I am trying to send an email in ASP.NET using the [`System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

However I am getting the following exception message:

> The parameter 'addresses' cannot be an empty string. Parameter name: addresses

This is my send email code:

```
private void SendEmailUsingGmail(string toEmailAddress)
{
    try
    {
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("keysketyyyy@gmail.com", 
         "sdsdasd");
        smtp.Port = 587;
        smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
        message.From = new MailAddress("keysketyyy@gmail.com");
        message.To.Add(toEmailAddress);
        message.Subject = "Write your email subject here";
        message.Body = "write the content of the email here";
        smtp.Send(message);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write("Error occured: " + ex.Message.ToString());
    }
}
```

The exception is being caught in the `SendEmailUsingGmail` catch block.

This is the calling code:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
   string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mydms"].ConnectionString;
   SqlConnection mySQLconnection = new SqlConnection(connStr);
   if (mySQLconnection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
   {
       mySQLconnection.Open();
       for (int i = 0; i < Repeater2.Items.Count; i++)
       {
           DropDownList DropDownListcontrol = ((DropDownList)Repeater2.Items[i].FindControl("DropDownList4"));
           Label DocId = ((Label)Repeater2.Items[i].FindControl("DocId"));
                  
           SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("approveddd", mySQLconnection);
           cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

           cmd.Parameters.Add("@DocID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32((DocId.Text));

           cmd.Parameters.Add("@ApproveID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(DropDownListcontrol.SelectedValue);
           cmd.Parameters.Add("@ApproveBy", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = (Session["Login2"]);
            try
            {
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                string emailId = ((Label)Repeater2.Items[i].FindControl("Label2")).Text;
                SendEmailUsingGmail(emailId);
             }
             catch (Exception ex)
             {
                 Supvisor.Text=(ex.Message);
             }
             cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
             //UPDATE APPPROVEID IN DOCUMENTINFO TABLE
             //DMSLIB.Doc myDoc = new DMSLIB.Doc();
             //myDoc.MarkDocAs(Convert.ToInt16(DocId.Text), 
             Convert.ToInt32(DropDownListcontrol.SelectedValue));
        }

    }
    else
    {
         Supvisor.Text = "Error";
    }
    if (mySQLconnection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
    {
         mySQLconnection.Close();
    }
 }
```

When an admin approves / rejects a document the data is saved into database like this:

```
SeqNo   DocID   ApproveID   ApproveBy
82      20      3           john
83      21      1           john
84      18      2           kety
85      19      1           emel
```

I also send an email when admins click a button, the email is sent to respective email ids like this, as I show in a repeater table:

```
 DocID  DocName Uplaodedfile    UserEmail           DocType DepType ApproveID
 1      ABC     def.pdf         abcdef@gmail.com    pdf     hr      (In this i set dropdown values are (approve/reject/pending)
```

Answer (score 9):

Make sure to use this line (note the `New MailAddress` declaration):

```
message.To.Add(New MailAddress(toEmailAddress));
```

and verify the contents of the variable `toEmailAddress` at submission time. This error occurs when it is empty.

Comment: when i add this it shows me error in this line ..Error 200 ) expected ,Error 201 Invalid expression term ')',Error 202 ; expected

Comment: What value have the variable "toEmailAddress"?

Comment: in this line i call a label ...(Label)Repeater2.Items[i].FindControl("Label2")).Text; in html like this   <td>
                                    <asp:Label Id="Label2" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                        <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "UserEmail")%>
                                    </td>

Comment: Ok, I understand. Put a breakpoint in this line
    "message.To.Add(toEmailAddress);" from the SendEmailUsingGmail method, 
and tell me your value.

Comment: Then this is your error, the "message.To.Add("");" is fail. You need verify the line "string emailId = ((Label)Repeater2.Items[i].FindControl("Label2")).Text;" in the Button1_Click. Chek the content of Label2.

Comment: how i check the content??and so what i done to solve this issue

Answer (score 3):

This exception is being thrown by the `MailAddress` constructor. It means you are trying to add an empty string as an email address, which is not valid.

In this case it means `toEmailAddress` is an empty string.